# Phonegap 3.4.0 fails to build new projects and update old projects

Tags: node.js, cordova, command-line, npm

I recently updated phonegap, node, and npm. I have an existing project I previously built with Phonegap version 3.3.0. I then attempted to update my existing project using `phonegap platform update ios` and received an error stating that the '/platforms' directory does not exist.
I don't think it makes any difference, but I also tried to use the cordova command instead of the phonegap command, but I just get the same error as above. I even created a completely new project with `phonegap create Test` and I am able to get a project built successfully, but when I try to run/build I get a similar error: `Error: /platforms does not exist. Please specify an existing parent folder. [error] /Users/mftcmbp1/.cordova/lib/ios/cordova/3.4.0/bin/create: Command failed with exit code 1` 
 Even stranger, I am able to successfully create a project with the cordova command, build ios and android platforms, and emulate the project, yet I can't do this with the phonegap command like I could before I updated.
Any help or suggestions of why this would be occurring will be helpful.
Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if there is a bug with Phonegap 3.4.0, but I fixed my issue by uninstalling the latest Phonegap version and installing Phonegap version 3.3.0-0.19.4.

Answer (score 1):

1- you need to 'cd' to your project and add platform first before build

```
cd Test
```

2- then add platform

iOS

```
phonegap platform add ios
```

android

```
phonegap platform add android
```

3- then you can build your project

iOS

```
phonegap build ios
```

android

```
phonegap build android
```

Comment: I was within the project when I got all these errors. Once I am in the project directory I try to build ios, and phonegap successfully detects iOS SDK environment and errors out while creating ios project with the following error: `Error: /platforms does not exist. Please specify an existing parent folder.` The command fails with exit code 1 if that helps any.

Comment: you need to add platform for ios first. phonegap platform add ios

Comment: I still get the same error "/platforms does not exist...". Its worth noting too that the above command is used for cordova. With the phonegap command you can just do `phonegap build ios`, at least with Phonegap 3.3.0

Comment: can u explain step by step how you do it in your question?

Comment: I have an existing project on my Desktop, titled "HRPO", which was built using Phonegap 3.3.0. I cd to that directory and try the command `cordova platform update ios`, just like the docs explain. I then get an error stating 'no such file or directory /platforms'. Ever since phonegap 3.0.0 you should be able to update with those commands, not create a brand new project and dump the www contents from the old to the new. Maybe thats what I have to do, since updating

Comment: just cd to your HRPO project. if possible, can I get yr phonegap project? I want to look at it.

Comment: I run all of these commands within my projects root directory.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this over the weekend, have you tried:

```
$ mkdir project_directory/platforms
```

As I remember it, that solved the issue as a hotfix.

The error occured after a project was cloned from github without the platforms directory.

Comment: I could have tried that, but there was a platforms directory withing the project

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue, and it looks like an error in the update script, and specifically this file:

`node_modules/phonegap/node_modules/cordova/src/util.js`

The quick fix is, in the function isRootDir, to change "config.xml" to ".cordova", i.e.:

`- if (fs.existsSync(path.join(dir, 'config.xml'))) {`
`+ if (fs.existsSync(path.join(dir, '.cordova'))) {`

The old version identified the base project directory via the existence of the .cordova directory.  The new version is incorrectly looking for a directory that contains these three items:

- www/
- config.xml
- platforms/

config.xml should not be in the base directory, it's under www/, which is why it fails.

The script does have fail-safe, which is to look for www/config.xml. However, the way it does this is to continue traversing the tree towards root, and if at any time it finds another www/config.xml, will assume this is a better candidate for the project directory.

In your situation, I'm guessing you have a /www/config.xml off of your root directory, and PhoneGap is erroneously thinking that is your project directory.

Comment: it didn't change anything in my case (phonegap@3.4.0)